# Google Analytics Reporting API - Failed to launch browser on production server

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-reporting-api

I'm using analytics reporting API v4 (c#). On my local machine everything works fine, but not in production on the webserver.

I have set up a OAuth 2.0 client ID in the google developers console for web application to both addresses ('http://localhost:12345', 'http://localhost:12345/Callback' and the actual domain on the server: 'http://example.com', 'http://example.com/Callback')

I don't think the error is connected to my code..  And I also read my json from a online-source, so it can not be related to user-read/write issues. And I have set full access to the folder App_Data in my project on the production-server. Here it is:

```
var path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");

var client = new WebClient();

var stream = client.OpenRead(https://api.myjson.com/bins/blahblah987654);

var loginEmailAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AnalyticsReporting.Email"];

return await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        new[] { AnalyticsReportingService.Scope.Analytics },
        loginEmailAddress, CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(path, fullPath: true));
```

On my local machine a file is created at this line: `new FileDataStore(path, fullPath: true));` But not on the server (even though I have full permission set to the App_Data-folder). And if I manually copy the file from local to production, it gets removed when the url containing above code is hit.

Comment: What is the error? Have you checked your authorised redirect URIs?

Comment: @sdhaus This is the errorPage I get: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=934254096895-8bt34v7n9qs3t0kjl04gan1arjb5kkb5.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http:%2F%2Flocalhost:55882%2Fauthorize%2F&scope=https:%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fanalytics. I dont know why it says "The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:55882/authorize,  does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client" whan the only redirectUrs I have set in developers console is http://example.com and http://example.com/Callback ?

Comment: Try creating a new credentials for the production server. It is a [best practice](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#scenarios) that the client credentials for prod/test/staging are different. It also takes sometime before the changes actually reflect. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

To get it to work, you need to visit your [console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/934254096895-8bt34v7n9qs3t0kjl04gan1arjb5kkb5.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=934254096895) (as per the error), and update your Authorised redirect URIs to include http://localhost:55882/authorize/

Note that this can take around 15 minutes to go live.

Whilst you have set up example.com and example.com/Callback, the error is saying that the actual URI that is redirecting for authentication is http://localhost:55882/authorize/.

You might want to check exactly how you are authenticating in production, as it shouldn't be redirecting through a localhost.

Comment: I can't understand why it's trying to authenticate to http://localhost:55882/authorize/ ? I have not used that url anywhere..